# What kind of security while using solid propellent?

Tags: propulsion, sugar-rocket

I'am going to to make a propulsion test with sugar and $\mathrm{KNO}_3$ (with large quantities).

What should I wear before to protect myself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a specific question about the use of personal protection equipment is way beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Absolutely do not do this.

Comment: Without knowing what "Large Quantities" are, this couldn't possibly be answered. In any case, making solid propellant is often illegal in most places, unless you have a proper license.

Comment: ...a good pair of running shoes. ;-)  Generally the correct approach is a good distance from the test site.

Comment: Meta discussion: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1026/58

Comment: Please read this first :   http://www.nakka-rocketry.net/index.html

Answer (score 10):

I would first like to state that I do not condone this experiment. Generally, if you don't already know the proper safety precautions, you SHOULD NOT perform the test. There is a large amount of energy stored in the conventional "backyard rocket fuel" you are mentioning. Temperatures could quickly reach a point where it will get out of control. If you plan to launch it, you will likely be violating a wide variety of city, state, and federal laws that are in place to protect against launching unstable projectiles.

I have no idea what size we are talking about, but a safe bet is that you want to wear heavy, fire resistant clothing. We are talking about potentially uncontrolled explosives here. Additionally, you should keep a safe distance of at least 500 ft, but possibly more when igniting. Safety glasses and ear protection are a must. Finally, you need to ensure that the containers being used are explosion resistant. The amount of ambiguity you have left makes me very concerned for your safety.

If you insist on following through with this test, I can not guarantee your safety.